# p-adically completed Hodge-completed de Rham algebra

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry

Let's look at [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.01921.pdf) on page 40.

Let $K$ be a finite extension of $\mathbb Q_p$. One can define the derived de Rham algebra $L\Omega_{\mathcal{O}_{\overline{K}}/\mathcal{O}_K}^{\bullet}$. There is a Hodge filtrations $F$ on it. Then according to the paper, we define the Hodge-completed de Rham algebra to be the projective system $L\widehat{\Omega}_{\mathcal{O}_{\overline{K}}/\mathcal{O}_K}^{\bullet}:=(L\Omega_{\mathcal{O}_{\overline{K}}/\mathcal{O}_K}^{\bullet}/F^i$). For simplicity we just write $L\Omega$ and $L\widehat{\Omega}=(L\Omega/F^i)$

My first question is: Here why don't we take the projecitve limit of this projective system?

After this we define the $p$-adic completion of $L\widehat{\Omega}$ by $L\widehat{\Omega}\widehat{\otimes}\mathbb{Z}_p$ which is the derived inverse limits $$R\varprojlim_n(L\widehat{\Omega}\otimes^L\mathbb Z/p^n\mathbb Z).$$

Now it starts to confuse me. Does it mean we take the derived inverse limit $R\varprojlim$ inside or outside the projective system $(L\Omega/ F^i)$? I mean does it matter we consider the system for $i$ first then $n$ or other way around?

Eventually if we compute its zeroth homology for each $n$ it is equal to $((A_{\mathrm{inf}}/(p^n))⟨t⟩/(t − \xi_n)^\widehat{}$ completed with respect to its divided power filtration. Why its $p$-adic completion is $(A_{\mathrm{inf}}⟨t⟩/(t − \xi))^\widehat{}$ completed with respect to its divided power filtration? Assume we could swap the two limits, then is the $p$-adic completion of $(A_{\mathrm{inf}}/(p^n))⟨t⟩/(t − \xi_n)$ simply $A_{\mathrm{inf}}⟨t⟩/(t − \xi)$?

Comment: I am not sure about their setting, but the Hodge-completed derived de Rham cohomology is an object in the subcategory of the filtered derived category spanned by those objects which are complete with respect to the filtration. I don't know what happens if one passes from filtered objects to pro-objects. In general, I think that the category of pro-objects in a large category is not very well behaved.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have some reference of filtered derived category?

Comment: Yes, the most recent is [Raksit's paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.02576). [Bhatt-Morrow-Scholze](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.03261) also has some discussion about that.